# Fabric.js - Fadeout an object and remove from canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How do you fade out an object on canvas and then remove that object?.

Also, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: activeObj.animate is not a function`, which is really odd as I can see in my code editor I have the animate method and its parameters available. Animate should be available to any object on canvas as far as I can see.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();

activeObj.setOpacity(1);
activeObj.animate('opacity', '0', {
  onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas) });
};
canvas.remove(activeObj);
```

Comment: @kangax Do you know how I'd do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem with the above code is that the call to remove the object is happening before the animation completes. You will need to use the `onComplete` options to remove the object after the animation is over.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('t');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas.add(circle);
canvas.setActiveObject(circle);
var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();

activeObj.setOpacity(1);

activeObj.animate('opacity', '0', {
  duration: 1000,
  onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
  onComplete: function() {
    canvas.remove(activeObj);
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="t" height="300" width="300">
```

Comment: This looks correct and I'll test it now. I found out why `.animate()` was not an available function. When you do the custom build it uses version 1.5 and doesn't seem to have the `.animate()` method available, even when you check each option. The full version of 1.6 however does work just fine.